# What is the string constant of button F3 in c#

Tags: c#, string, tcp

I have a c# code where i need to add the string constant of Button `F3` but i dont have any idea.Its a function Key ..

I need to use this constant to my TCP IP client code..

I am working with TCP ip Socket. At present i have code for F3 button press in windows Form Key for CMD.exe using TELNET but i want it to get converted into Socket client to send the command ..

Here is my code..

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F3}");//This is for Command Prompt
```

This i need to change into ..

```
byte[] aSpace = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Equivalent of F3" );
stream.Write(aSpace, 0, aSpace.Length);
```

Please help me..

Comment: Depends on what you are using the `F3` for, the closest thing I can think of is the [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) enum, but if you are not working with forms that is not the right enum to use. Are you looking for `F3`'s [scan code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode)?

Comment: Why not ask your two issues of the same kind in a single question? Are you opening a question for every single key now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789412/what-is-the-keypress-code-for-tab-button-press

Comment: @floele I am sorry sir but i thought it a different question..

Answer (score 0):

`F3` does not have a character representation, it is considered a "meta" key. You will need to rethink your protocol and figure out a way to handle meta key representations.

Perhaps you use a placeholder string (like `{F3}` SendKeys uses, or `^[OR` that [SSH uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh)). Perhaps you make a enum of all the meta keys you want to handle and and modify your protocol so you can both send strings and the enum values using some kind of header to tell the difference. Perhaps make a class that represents a "Message" and use a serialization library like [`protobuf`](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to handle all that stuff for you.

You have many options open, but you will need to pick one and design it in to your message protocol between machines.

Comment: Sir what does sir what does this do System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F3}"); mean ..Is is to close the TELNET connection from the cmd.If yes i can close my socket client which will do the same job..

Comment: What it does is it parses the string and checks to see if it sees the string patern `"{ ... }"` Then it uses a lookup table inernally to see that string `{F3}` represents the meta key `F3` and sends the meta key to the application.